# How exec works on Linux

Tags: c, unix, exec

I'm trying to understand how exec works and now i'm stuck on this example. Without deleting anything from the provided text, edit the below function so that the program applies the command to all the arguments received and how this is done? Thanks! :)

```
int main(int argc, char** argv[]){
for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){
    execlp("cat", "cat", argv[i]);
    printf("Error\n");
    exit(1);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The example program is wrong. Use [`man execlp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) to find out how to use it correctly, and to see related functions that will help you complete your homework problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. "I'm stuck" doesn't tell us what specifically you don't understand. What info in the [execlp man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) in particular do you not understand?

Comment: What happens after the first loop? Is the code overwritten? And how to correct the code?

Comment: Unless the `execlp` call fails then there is no "after the first loop". On success the `exec` family of calls "replaces the current process image with a new process image". That is, on success, none of the code after the `execlp` will be executed. How to correct the code is your homework that you need to attempt on your own after reading and understanding the relevant material. We can help you understand any of the material you have specific doubts about.

Comment: So, i'll have only one cat with the first argument, remaining arguments will be deleted?

Comment: No, you need to modify the code such that `cat` is called with *all* the provided arguments.

Comment: But how do i now how many arguments do i have?

Comment: how many arugments?  the `argc -1` is the number of command line arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the execlp() will replace the current process.

Note: the last parameter to `execlp()` must be NULL

to avoid the current process being overlayed, the first step is to call `fork()` to create a child process.

naturally allow for each of the possible returned values from fork()`

Then the parent process needs to wait for the child process to exit.

Otherwise multiple child processes, each running `cat`, will be in a race to display their output on the terminal.

So the parent needs to wait for each child to complete before creating the next child process

Applying all the above results in:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h> // waitpid()
#include <unistd.h>   // fork()
#include <stdio.h>    // perror()  
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE


int main(int argc, char* argv[])  // single `*` when using `[]`
{
    pid_t pid;

    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
        switch( pid = fork() )
        {
        case -1:
            // handle error
            perror( "fork failed");
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            break;

        case 0: // the child
            execlp("cat", "cat", argv[i], NULL);
            perror("execlp failed");
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            break;

        default:
            // parent
            // wait for child to exit
            waitpid( pid, NULL, 0);
            break;
        } // end switch
    } // end for
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```